# Why can't I use cal command to display calendar in Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, calendar

I am using Git Bash in Windows 10.
When I typed in "cal" in Git Bash, it says "bash: cal: command not found."
Then I typed in where cal, it says "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

I know that this is a discrepancy between Unix and Git Bash, but is there a way to show calendar in Git Bash as it does in Unix?

Comment: isn't possible to install it?

Comment: Git bash is a shell, cal is likely to be a unix program. Consider installing it? However it may not run on windows

Answer (score 4):

If you want a larger feature set of Unix tools on W10, you may want to consider [installing the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). It provides a full compatibility layer between Windows and the installed Linux distro. You can install most Linux tools this way.